# How to use CKO_VENDOR_DEFINED in pkcs#11

Tags: pkcs#11

Has anyone used CKO_VENDOR_DEFINED to create a key or a data object?

There is hardly any documentation (including the mother load from Oasis) about how to do it, or which attributes are applicable/not-applicable.

Unfortunately, but hopefully understandably, I can not describe exactly what I am trying to do.

But the gist of it is that I need to be able to have a bit more attribute<=>mechanism flexibility with our kind of keys and the ability to modify a key on the token.

I'd really appreciate any pointers or help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [OpenPGP extension to PKCS #11](http://openfortress.nl/doc/spec/pgp-in-pkcs11/) where CKC_OPENPGP is defined as:

```
#define CKC_OPENPGP  (CKC_VENDOR_DEFINED|0x00504750)
```

I've seen also commercial implementations introducing CK*_VENDOR_DEFINED extensions this way.

Answer (score 0):

(AFAIK) vendor defined object types must be implemented inside the HSM unit firmware (in theory, the host-side cryptoki library could introduce some additional "virtual" object types, but this probably would not make any sense as the overall security model would stay the same -- because the host-side cryptoki code runs in an untrusted execution environment).

If you need more control than provided by the vanilla PKCS#11 you have some choices:

1. **Use existing vendor extensions** -- some vendors add their own extensions designed to solve common use-cases. Read your documentation or contact your vendor directly.
2. **Implement a custom firmware** -- some products allow the end-user to run a custom code *inside* the HSM device. You can implement your model this way.

SafeNet ProtectServer:

> SafeNet ProtectServer HSMs offer a unique level of flexibility for
>   application developers to create their own firmware and execute it
>   within the secure confines of the HSM. Known as functionality modules,
>   the toolkits provide a comprehensive facility to develop and deploy
>   custom firmware.

Thales nShield:

> Most nShield HSMs also support the unique ability to host critical
>   applications within the hardened security boundary, so you can
>   establish tamper-resistant business processes in addition to
>   protecting cryptographic operations.

Utimaco CryptoServer:

> The CryptoServer Software Development Kit (SDK) is the professional
>   development environment for all Utimaco Hardware Security Modules. It
>   enables integrators and end-users to create specific applications,
>   e.g. proprietary algorithms, custom key derivation procedures or
>   complex protocols that run in the tamper-proof environment of the
>   CryptoServer Hardware Security Module. As the SDK provides full access
>   to the Utimaco base firmware, custom firmware modules can be developed
>   in a very short time frame.

3. **Use some other technology** -- do not use HSMs at all and leverage some other secure device. Specifically smartcards might be a viable alternative as some of them can be programmed (at least [Java Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card) or [MULTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MULTOS) ones). On the other hand the performance and range of supported algorithms is quite limited here (depends on your use-case).