# What will be the return value of C_CreateObject(in PKCS#11) if token not supported?

Tags: pkcs#11

I am working on a library which follows PKCS#11 standard.

https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/

The library can generate RSA Keypair in token by the function C_GenerateKeyPair and returns appropriate object handles with return value CKR_OK.

The token(applet) not supports load of private/public key except generate key pair. **What will be the appropriate return value** of create RSA private/public key using C_CreateObject?

Now I am returning CKR_GENERAL_ERROR, is it okay?

Allowed return values are

> CKR_ARGUMENTS_BAD, CKR_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY,
> CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID, CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID,
> CKR_CRYPTOKI_NOT_INITIALIZED, CKR_DEVICE_ERROR, CKR_DEVICE_MEMORY,
> CKR_DEVICE_REMOVED, CKR_DOMAIN_PARAMS_INVALID, CKR_FUNCTION_FAILED,
> CKR_GENERAL_ERROR, CKR_HOST_MEMORY, CKR_OK, CKR_PIN_EXPIRED,
> CKR_SESSION_CLOSED, CKR_SESSION_HANDLE_INVALID, CKR_SESSION_READ_ONLY,
> CKR_TEMPLATE_INCOMPLETE, CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT,
> CKR_TOKEN_WRITE_PROTECTED, CKR_USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN.

Thanks for your help

**Update**

I have two types of applet, one supports load of RSA private/public key to token and another not supports. It can only possible to identify if the token supports load of key is the response of transmitted APDU. So I can't take decision only to check the class attribute of C_CreateObject.

Answer (score 0):

If your library does not support `C_CreateObject` at all then the best choice IMO is `CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

Chapter 11 in [PKCS#11 v2.20](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/tree/master/v2.20) states:

> A Cryptoki library need not support every function in the Cryptoki API. However, even an unsupported function must have a "stub" in the library which simply returns the value `CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

If your library does support `C_CreateObject` for creation of other object types (e.g. certificates, data objects etc.) then the best choice IMO is `CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID`.

Chapter 10.1.1 in [PKCS#11 v2.20](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/tree/master/v2.20) states:

> If the supplied template specifies an invalid value for a valid attribute, then the attempt should fail with the error code `CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID`.

#### UPDATE

Now that you have shared more details about your library in the comments I can add more detailed explanation:

It seems I can call your implementation of `C_CreateObject` with template containing `CKA_CLASS=CKO_CERTIFICATE` and it will  create certificate object on this particular token and return `CKR_OK`. If I call it with template containing `CKA_CLASS=CKO_PRIVATE_KEY` then your code will decide to return an error right after the evaluation of the supplied value of this attribute. IMO there is no doubt that chapter 10.1.1 of [PKCS#11 v2.20](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/tree/master/v2.20) recommends you to return `CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID` in this case.

However if are not willing to follow behavior recommended by the specification and there is no predefined error code you like, you can introduce your own vendor defined code (see [my older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35807515/3325704) for more details):

```
#define CKR_TOKEN_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED (CKR_VENDOR_DEFINED|0x0000001)
```

IMO confusion level for inexperienced developer will be the same regardless of error code you return. In the end he/she will need to consult your documentation or logs produced by your library to find out the real reason why he/she received the error.

Comment: My library supports C_CreateObject for data and certificate object.
The same template is valid for another token(applet) which supports write private/public key. So it is little confusing for the application developer if i use `CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID`. It would be helpful if there is any return value named **CKR_TOKEN_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED** or something like this which indicates that the operation is not supported by token. Thanks for your answer.